# Can ComboBoxItem holds object value?

Tags: asp.net

From my experience in silverlight, their comboBoxItem can holds object data, so I can do like ComboBox.selectedItem and cast to the data object type and get the databinding object out.

But in Asp.Net, the ComboBoxItem seems like only have Text and Value property for databinding.
I wonder if there is a way that I can get the databinding object out?
Not with searching the datasource and find the object by Text and Value...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in the code behind with VB...

```
CType(ddlDropDownList.Items(ddlDropDownList.SelectedIndex), ObjectType)
```

Comment: The code aboves seems like just converting the DropDownList item to the object type that I use for the DropDownList.  But the problem is, Asp doesn't like Silverlight which can cast their DropDownItem to the data object.  So that's my quetions, is there any way I can take the data object out?   Like, is there any parameter in DropDownItem that actually is reference to the Data Object?

Comment: Silly me, drop down list items are listitem objects.  Try setting the DataValueField to a primary key in the datasource so that you can requery for the object using that ID.

Comment: Seems like that will be the only way to do it I guess, I just wonder if there is any smart way avoid searching the datasource, thanks...